# How to get Rails "new" path after failed form-input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, crud, rails-i18n, language-switching

I am implementing a simple language switcher in the common HTML menu-bar on a website in Rails, where the locale is *path-based* with the Rails-standard I18n implementation, e.g., `/en/articles` for Index for the Article model in *English* (in the following example, I consistently use pages for the model `Article`).

The language switcher is a simple text link (`<a>` in HTML) to the same page in another language. For example, the French page for `/en/article/7` should be `/fr/article/7`.
Here is the most simplified code for the language-switcher link, which preserves all the GET query parameters for the current page:

```rb
str_link = link_to("fr", url_for(locale: "fr", params: request.query_parameters.except("locale")))
```

This code is included inside the common layout `/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` so that it is applied to all pages on the website.
This works most of time but fails on the page after a user-input to a `new` page turns out to be invalid (`status: :unprocessable_entity`), according to the Rails standard CRUD action.

In the `new` page, the required link for the language switcher for French should be `/fr/article/new`; the above code-snippet works fine when a user freshly opens the `new` page in English (`/en/article/new`). However, once a user's input turns out to be invalid, the given URL is `/en/articles`, whose contents are equivalent to the `new` page.

How can I obtain the path `/en/article/new` in such cases so as to make the language switcher provide the correct link?

Obviously, when a user just requests the Index page `/en/articles`, the counterpart French page is `/fr/articles`, the URL of which is identical to the failed `new` page. So, they must be distinguished, that is, the path cannot be guessed thoroughly from the current URL and it depends on whether it is a fresh request or `unprocessable_entity`.

An answer to the question "[Ruby on Rails Link to Previous Page on Form Failing After Invalid Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68716684/ruby-on-rails-link-to-previous-page-on-form-failing-after-invalid-input)" suggests implementing `hidden_field` that contains the `new` page URL and the algorithm uses it. However, the suggestion does not work well in this case because the `hidden_field` for action `create` is *POST* and not a GET parameter. In the present case of the *common* language switcher, I need to deal with an arbitrary number of models inside the *common* layout (`application.html.erb`), meaning which parameter in `params` to *permit* cannot be pre-determined and hence to access `hidden_field` in `params` is tricky.

Here are the *routes* and `Article` Controller generated according to the Rails standard:

```bash
% bin/rails g scaffold Article title:string content:text
```

Routes:

```rb
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  filter :locale
  resources :articles
end
```

`Article` Controller:

```rb
# app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.html { redirect_to article_url(@article), notice: "Article was successfully created." }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :content)
    end
end
```

I am using Rails 7.0. But I think the Rails version is almost irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

The language needs to be defined as a variable in your routes:

```rb
# config/routes.rb
scope "/:locale" do
  resources :articles
end
```

This puts a language parameter in all your routes. Now you have to make sure that it's well-defined everywhere, as described [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#managing-the-locale-across-requests)

```rb
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  around_action :switch_locale

  def switch_locale(&action)
    locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
    I18n.with_locale(locale, &action)
  end
end
```

And you need to define the default locale somewhere, e.g. in an intializer:

```rb
# config/initializers/locale.rb
  Rails.application.config.i18n.default_locale = I18n.default_locale = :en
```

Comment: Oops, sorry I forgot to include the statement `filter :locale` in `routes.rb` in my question – I have now edited the question. I understand it means the same as your suggested `routes.rb`. The i18n environment is appropriately set in the same way as your answer (I expressed it *path-based* in my question) and is working. My question is how to write the `<a>` for the language switcher after a failed-*create* page.